# reloadData only on tableView visible cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

Is that possible? To reload only the cells that are visible in order to do it more efficient.

Comment: How about providing some context? What language/framework/library/anything?

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm programming in objetive-C language (iOS SDK 4.0)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's how table views work by default. The `UITableView` class never loads cells until they're about to appear onscreen, even when you call `reloadData`.

Comment: jlehr@can you provide any reference

Comment: There will be as many cells loaded (and created) which intersect with the scroll view's frame, even when portions of the frame are not visible. This of course only happens in certain scenarios where the table view is itself a subview of another scroll view and where the frame's size would match its content size and scrolling would be disabled for the table view and achieved by the embedding scroll view.

Comment: This is outdated as of iOS 10 due to cell prefetching. Post iOS 10 `cellForRow` is called slightly before the cell will be visible.

Comment: No, it is a wrong answer.You can't use `reloadData` in a lot of cases. For example if you  insert/delete rows with animation `reloadata` breaks this animation

Answer (score 16):

To reload visible cells of tableview in Swift 3.0:

```
guard let visibleRows = pTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else { return }

pTableView.beginUpdates()

pTableView.reloadRows(at: visibleRows, with: .none)

pTableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. But please guard indexPathsForVisibleRows against nil for empty tableViews.

Answer (score 14):

Try this, You can reload any cell of the tableview using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I found only following places can use 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths':

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 - (IBAction) unwindToMealList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) sender