# FSCalendar Inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fscalendar

I'm using `FSCalendar` in tableview cell, calendar is working fine but their is an issue while reusing the cell by scrolling up the tableview to the calendar. The tableview became glitchy. Below is my code inside cell for row at indexPath:

```
let calendarCell = calendarTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarReuse")
let calendarView = calendarCell.viewWithTag(1) as! FSCalendar
calendarView.delegate = self
calendarView.dataSource = self
calendarView.register(DIYCalendarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
calendarView.reloadData()
return calendarCell
```

I'm trying to remove `calendarView.reloadData()` the table view is working fine, but the calendar not loading data anymore.

Find the link of the design here:

[image: Design]

Comment: How's your design and how many calendar view in your tableView ??

Comment: @YashBhikadiya here's a screenshot of the design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzKKE.png

Comment: you can add CalendarView in tableViewHeader instead of cellForRowAt indexPath.Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I would also suggest not using `reloadData()`, as that reloads everything and you end up doing work you don't need to. Here's another way reload visible cells. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41032394/4475605.